# Gesture Recognition in Google Glass

Tags: gesture-recognition, google-glass, google-mirror-api, motion-detection

I need to know about a feature in Google glass, whether it is available or not. I have been told that google glass contains a feature called "Gesture Detection using Camera". In other words, a system where it responds to hand commands and signals. I believe this is true because I have seen some half baked articles, with full of uncertainty. If this is true and something like that exists for real, from where can I get more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the current Glassware APIs but its reasonable to guess this would be feasible in the not-yet-released native SDK.  In the meantime, its just speculation